# How can I put this SAPUI5 property in JSON writing (listener property)

Tags: javascript, json, sapui5

I have this variable (oKunde2) and I want to put the attachBrowserEvent as a listener into the sap.ui.commons.Textfield(). But whatever I try it doesnt work.

```
var oKunde2 = new sap.ui.commons.TextField({ width: "50%", 
                                             id: "kunde", 
                                             enabled: true});
    oKunde2.attachBrowserEvent("keyup", function (event) {
            var key = event.keyCode || event.which;

            if (key === 13) {
                pressHandler();
            }
            return false;
        });
```

This is my code vor this specific variable and I hop you can help.

Comment: Your code seems alright... Is your textfield displayed correctly?

Comment: @Qualiture yes it does, but I dont want to make my code bigger then necessary and I think a listener property after the enabled would be much shorter

Comment: I understand, but if you look at the API, this is not possible; since there is no property for it, you could only use the `attachBrowserEvent` method https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.Control.html

Comment: I see thanks, write it as an answer then I can choose it

Comment: Naah, it's hardly an answer anyway ;-)